# Eclipse - Java - Hotswap without breakpoints

Tags: java, eclipse, hotswap

I have a question.
Is it possible to use the hotswap without using breakpoints ?

When notch made prelude of chambered (http://www.youtube.com/user/Nizzotch?feature=playlist-comment#p/u) he used the hotswap without having to :
- add breakpoints
- save
- remove breakpoint
- resume
In this video it's too fast to see that, but i can't find old ones.

Do you have an idea ? eclipse-options, macro, plugins ... ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on your JVM, but hotswap in Eclipse worked for me with no tricks on the Sun's HotSpot JVM back in the times of Java 1.5. Here's [a related Sun's bug](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4287595). Which JVM are you using?

```
public class Test {
    private static int ctr = 0;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        while (true) {
            method();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(200);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.err.println("Interrupted");
            }
        }
    }
    
    private static void method() {
        System.out.println(ctr);
    }
}
```

I changed `System.out.println(ctr);` to `System.out.println(ctr++);`, and my output altered to an increasing sequence.

Comment: Java version : 1.6.0_30. I can use the hotswap when i use breakpoints. But if the code is running when i save, then my modifications are not taken.

Comment: OK, are you running in the Debug mode? See [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2673554/hot-code-replace-not-working-eclipse-doesnt-change-any-code-on-jboss) for a possible solution.

Comment: Yes i run in the debug mode and unlike your linked question, the changes are applied. Test yourself you will see. Create a project, a main method, and another method. In the second method, put an output message surrounded by a infinite loop. Then debug it. If you make a change in the message, and save nothing hapened, and your file is no longer linked. So make a new try, launch debug. Add a breakpoint on the output message, change it and save. Now resume and it's ok. But it's too much step compared when notch debug his application.

Comment: Oh, I seem to get the point. Chances are that the JVM cannot hotswap code of existing stackframes without a breakpoint (in which case the affected frames are removed off the stack, and the entry call is executed once again.) I have added an example - it worked for me ONLY in the Debug mode.