# Getting hot code replace working (Eclipse EE juno, Jboss AS 7.1)

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss

I have referred to the question [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2673554/hot-code-replace-not-working-eclipse-doesnt-change-any-code-on-jboss) and have been unable to resolve my issue at all.

I'm making a dynamic web project that uses jsp / css as well as jquery.   Right now I need to stop the server, clean, and republish.

I have build automatically checked, I have selected automatically publish on the server... I'm not really sure if I'm missing something but I'd love to get this working as frontend development without realtime editing is horrid.

I'm not using maven or any other form of source control (yet)(I can add in ivy, if need be?)

Thanks.!

[Image of server setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QEn0q.png)

[image: I also have build automatically checked.]

Comment: Are you using [jboss tools](https://www.jboss.org/tools)?

Comment: I have a couple of them installed but I don't know how to configure them or what they do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your are using the [JBoss Server Manager](http://docs.jboss.org/tools/3.2.1.GA/en/as/html_single/index.html) that came with the [Jboss Tools Suite](http://docs.jboss.org/tools/3.2.1.GA/) you have to mark the "Automatically publish when resources change" option of the "Publishing" section of your Jboss Server Configuration.

You can find the Jboss Tools for Juno [here](http://www.jboss.org/tools), or you can use the Jboss Developer Studio IDE, that is an Eclipse Indigo + Jboss Tools like explained [here](http://www.jboss.org/jdf/examples/ticket-monster/tutorial/Introduction/) (I'm using it, and it runs way better than eclipse, don't know why, but that's just my experience)